# Storing values in a container

Tags: c++, list, class, containers

I'm trying to read two values from a file and store them in my class called `God`. `God` has two data members, `name` and `mythology`. I wish to store the values in a `list<God>` (the god and its respective mythology) and then print them out. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class God {
    string name;
    string mythology;
public:
    God(string& a, string& b) {
        name=a;
        mythology =b;
    }
    friend ostream&  operator<<( ostream& os,const God&);
};

void read_gods(list<God>& s) {
    string gname, gmyth;

    //reading values from file
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("gods.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> gname >> gmyth ;
        s.push_back(God(gname, gmyth));
    }
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream& os,const God& god) {
    return  os << god.name << god.mythology;
}

int main() {
    //container:
    list<God> Godmyth;
    read_gods(Godmyth);

    cout << Godmyth;

    return 0;
}
```

If for example I read in Zeus, Greek then how would I be able to access them?

The error I'm receiving is:

> error: `cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|`

Comment: You could make a `std::map<string, God>` so you could access the objects by name.

Comment: You need to define get member functions to access your members

Comment: What are you having problems with? Your title suggests you want to know how to store values in a container.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should not do `while (!inFile.eof())`, this is because the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read beyond the end of the file. This causes the loop to iterate once to many. Instead do e.g. `while (inFile >> ...)`.

Comment: I know how to store values into a container like `list<double>` but now I want to know how to store God in a container and then access the name and mythology respectively. Thanks for the tip @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: Then change the title so that it relates to the question you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You should write either `operator <<` or some member function for class God that outputs its data members.

For example

```
class God
{
public:
   std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const
   {
      return os << name << ": " << mythology;
   }

   //...
};
```

Or

```
class God
{
public:
   friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const God & ); 

   //...
};


std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const God &god )
{
    return os << god.name << ": " << god.mythology;
}
```

In this case instead of invalid statement

```
cout << Godmyth << endl;
```

you could write

```
for ( const God &god : Godmyth ) std::cout << god << std::endl;
```

Or if you simply want to access the data members then you should write getters.

For example

```
class God
{
public:
    std::string GetName() const { return name; }
    std::string GetMythology() const { return mythology; }
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overloaded `operator<<` allowing printing [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)'s content using `std::cout`.

What you can do?

1. As @Vlad mentioned, you can write

   ```
   for ( const God &god : Godmyth )
       std::cout << god << '\n';
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can write your own `operator<<`:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const std::list<T> &_list){
       os << "[\n";
       for ( const auto &item : _list )
           os << item << ";\n";
       return os << ']';
   }
   ```